# Should I use encapsulation in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, class, encapsulation

I'm programming in TypeScript for like 3 months, but I never used encapsulation, as I also do Java and I use encapsulation everywhere in Java, I'm asking here if I should also do that in TypeScript.

I found nothing about that in the documentation and same in the Guidelines.

So, should I use encapsulation for my classes in TypeScript ?

Comment: First off, how do _you_ define encapsulation? Is this merely doing the brilant Java getX/setX “pattern” or..?

Comment: Yeah this is exactly this.

Comment: Nothing wrong with encapsulation but JavaScript folks don't seem to like it much.

Comment: Overall, I find that setters as a construct are overused and “encapsulation via wrappers” is a lip-service. While these “hide” the fields, they don’t “hide” the larger semantic constructs.. anyway, TS allows one to go back and [convert a field to a property **retroactively** (only requiring the definition change)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/typescript-accessor/), *which pretty much makes the question moot*. (In Java you’re hosed if wishing to switch later.)

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree with the terminology choice. Using getters / setters is nice and all if you're preparing for possible future changes, but in the present day it's no better than simple public fields. You're not actually *encapsulating* anything, just making it more obtuse to access. Encapsulation would be carrying internal state but only providing specific methods to access or mutate it in the ways you intend. Providing a full getter / setter pair gives the caller full control over the data, which is contrary to the notion.

Comment: Yeah thanks @Silvio Mayolo.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, I feel like TypeScript has the right balance of JavaScript-isms (the flexible data structures, first-class functions etc) but also the strong type system of say, C#.

I think you *should* use encapsulation, since it's a language feature. The important part is you have a lot more say in *how much* you do it. JavaScript already has built-in [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) so you can achieve a lot of encapsulation ideas without even using TypeScript!

I've found in my own personal projects that encapsulation is a helpful construct, but you need it less in TypeScript. I'm not sure why, but passing plain JS objects around makes my class structures a lot simpler (since I can structure my data in arbitrary ways).

I think the important part is finding the balance that:

1. Is maintainable
2. Works with the projects that you (and your team potentially) are working on.

Comment: "you should use encapsulation, since it's a language feature" --- that looks like a very weak point.

Comment: “Use encapsulation” means ..?

Comment: Based on `getX`/`setX` comment on the question, my interpretation is that "use encapsulation" means using private/protected instance variables making some accessibly publicly via accessors.

I argue for it because, it's currently not a language feature of JavaScript (although I know there's a proposal out there for it). Therefore, the language designers _put it into the language deliberately_ because they thought it provided value to developer workflows